# Generic comparison method for two tables in BigQuery if tables contain STRUCT type

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, comparison, difference, set-difference

I'm looking for a generic method to compare two tables in BigQuery, even if they have columns that are STRUCT type.

It should work for any pair of tables, and ideally wouldn't involve writing a query that depends on that actual columns of the tables.  All I really need to know is if the tables are equal or not, but it would be a bonus if it could show me the difference between the rows that aren't the same.

So something like (in pseudo code)

`sizeOf( TABLE A EXCEPT TABLE B ) == 0`

or

`Hash(TABLE A) == HASH(TABLE B)`

Would be fine.

I tried using this:

```
(   SELECT * FROM table1
    EXCEPT DISTINCT
    SELECT * FROM table2)  
UNION ALL
(   SELECT * FROM table2
    EXCEPT DISTINCT
    SELECT * FROM table1)
```

But I got this error.

```
Column 1 in EXCEPT ALL has type that does not support set operation comparisons: STRUCT at [3:5]
```

Does anyone know of a way to get around this?

## EDIT

Should have mentioned before, but I need this to work regardless of the ordering of the rows of the table.

Comment: you can't compare array and struct types, first you need to cast them to string, for example to json string `to_json_string(<your_struct_column>)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think yo are looking for something like below to start with

```
#standardSQL
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(a) FROM `project.dataset.tableA` a
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(b) FROM `project.dataset.tableB` b
```

Or, more complete example - to show differences - note: this can be quite exhausting output for really different tables

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 'a' table, * FROM (
  SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(a) record FROM `project.dataset.tableA` a
  EXCEPT DISTINCT
  SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(b) FROM `project.dataset.tableB` b
)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', * FROM (
  SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(b) FROM `project.dataset.tableB` b
  EXCEPT DISTINCT
  SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(a) FROM `project.dataset.tableA` a
)
```

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific in my question.  But I need this to work regardless of the ordering of the rows in the table.  This solution does seems to work correctly when tables contain the same data in the same order.

Comment: i am not sure i see what you mean and where the order is involved! solution i proposed has no dependency on ordering the rows

Comment: Thanks Mikhail your method does work.  I had a problem with my data which is why I thought it didn't at first.

Comment: thank you for confirming - I feel better now and glad it worked for you :o)